# Map Consumer Groups to Topics within Confluent Kafka client

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

In my application, which uses .NET Confluent Kafka SDK, I want to retrieve topics with related consumer groups and related partitions, and get lag information per partition.

SDK provides functionality to retrieve:

1. All topics

```
use consumer = new Consumer(config)
let metadata = consumer.GetMetadata(true, timeout)
let allTopics = metadata.Topics
```

2. All consumer groups

```
use consumer = new Consumer(config)
let groups = consumer.ListGroups(timeout)
```

But there is no interface on how to map these 2 lists.

Why there is no such functionality and is that possible to map lists somehow?

Comment: I would suggest using an external tool like Burrow for lag purposes. Also groups contain topics; topics know nothing about their groups. This applies to all kafka clients

Comment: eventually this is not an option to use an external tool. And Group definition does not contain any information related to the topic

Comment: There should be `AdminClient.ListGroups`, then that has `GroupInfo` with `Members` ... https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/src/Confluent.Kafka/GroupMemberInfo.cs#L22-L26 Basically, don't use the Consumer; you don't need it. But if you did want to use an external tool, its really just a REST API call, at that point